# Sum cells from a workbook and paste in another workbook

Tags: vba, excel

I have 2 workbooks and I need to copy the sum of 2 cells in a cell of another workbook. I'm copying values normaly, but in one case I need to copy the sum of 2 cells. I'm trying with this code, but it doesn't work:

```
Sub Excel_Excel()
Dim x As ThisWorkbook
Dim y As Workbook
Dim Total As Double

Application.ScreenUpdating = False
Application.DisplayAlerts = False

''allow the user to select one file
Application.FileDialog(msoFileDialogOpen).AllowMultiSelect = False
''make the file dialog visible to the user
intChoice = Application.FileDialog(msoFileDialogOpen).Show
''determine what choice the user made
If intChoice <> 0 Then
''get the file path selected by the user
    strPath = Application.FileDialog(msoFileDialogOpen).SelectedItems(1)

End If

'## Open workbook:
Set y = Workbooks.Open(strPath)

'Now, copy what you want from y:
y.Sheets("Deducciones").Range("F70:F86").Copy
'Now, paste to ThisWorksheet x:
ThisWorkbook.Sheets("Deducciones").Range("rngdeducciónID").PasteSpecial    xlPasteValues

'Define range that you need to sum, sum it and copy:
range1 = y.Sheets("Deducciones").Range("F87:F88")
Total = WorksheetFunction.Sum(Range(range1))
y.Sheets("Deducciones").Total.Copy
'Now, paste to ThisWorksheet x:
ThisWorkbook.Sheets("Deducciones").D86.PasteSpecial

'Close y:
y.Close

End Sub
```

This code is not working: Total = WorksheetFunction.Sum(Range(range1))

Comment: Why don't you just use =sum(...)?

Comment: You mean directly from one workbook to the other? I need to import data from one workbook, choosing it from a folder as I do it in the code and them import data from that workbook, but in some cases i need to import the sum of 2 cells, instead of just copying the content...

Answer (score 0, accepted):

How about doing it like below:

```
Sub Excel_Excel()
Dim x As ThisWorkbook
Dim y As Workbook
Dim Total As Double

Application.ScreenUpdating = False
Application.DisplayAlerts = False

''allow the user to select one file
Application.FileDialog(msoFileDialogOpen).AllowMultiSelect = False
''make the file dialog visible to the user
intChoice = Application.FileDialog(msoFileDialogOpen).Show
''determine what choice the user made
If intChoice <> 0 Then
''get the file path selected by the user
    strPath = Application.FileDialog(msoFileDialogOpen).SelectedItems(1)

End If

'## Open workbook:
Set y = Workbooks.Open(strPath)

'Now, copy what you want from y:
y.Sheets("Deducciones").Range("F70:F86").Copy
'Now, paste to ThisWorksheet x:
ThisWorkbook.Sheets("Deducciones").Range("rngdeducciónID").PasteSpecial xlPasteValues

'Define range that you need to sum, sum it and add to variable Total:
Total = WorksheetFunction.Sum(y.Sheets("Deducciones").Range("F87:F88"))
'Now, pass the value of Total to ThisWorksheet x:
ThisWorkbook.Sheets("Deducciones").Range("D86").Value = Total

'Close y:
y.Close
End Sub
```

Comment: Please could you mark my response as an asnwer, if it has helped? Thanks.

Comment: I was trying to vote but I don't have enough reputation... sorry!